# No power from USB once connector is on the PCB

Tags: usb, connector

[image]I have attempted to replace a micro USB connector on a PCB. It is used to charge the battery of the device. Once it was in place and I connected the charging cable I measured the voltage on pin 1 (probe on ground and probe on pin 1), I got nothing.

I then desoldered the connector and measured again with the charging cable plugged in, and there was 5 V on pin 1 on the connector.

What can cause the voltage on pin 1 to disappear once the connector is on the board? I had my probe on the actual pin of the connector, not on the trace. The pins were not bridged.

I've included a pic. It's a little blobby but the pins aren't bridged.

Additional:

The original connector was badly damaged. I think I may need a different connector with reversed polarity.

Comment: Sounds like you shorted the pin to ground while soldering. Perhaps a solder bridge to a mounting pad?

Comment: Sorry, I just did a ninja edit. No solder bridge. I didn't measure a short either.

Comment: Need more info, a pic would be nice. Sometimes flux can leave oxides that are hard to probe

Comment: Thank you both. I will add pic as soon as I can.

Comment: Can you do a continuity test on the power leads ? (off power of course). Also the 2 passives below the connector look burned no ?

Comment: Thank you . Pin 1 is actually going to ground. So I created short with this type of connector. The two components below the pins have been baked by hot air. I have been focussed on the USB connector, I have not tested further. Anyone know a source for an upside down USB Micro?

Comment: Unplug the USB and measure the resistance between + and - port and report back.

Comment: I've had trouble with hand soldering that style of USB connector where the metal 'flap' which bends down over the back got some solder underneath it and shorted to the pins.

Comment: Thank you. I did check underneath. The pins look clean all to way to the plastic. I checked on Google what the port looked like, and it the original port is indeed flipped upside down, which means that 5V is on the opposite pin. I found a replacement port and I hope I didn't fry the board.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all.

I believe it will not be worth the trouble getting a new connector. I've tested the board today and I'm getting a short to ground on the connector and the two components right below the pins seem dead as well. Lesson to me not to assume anything and double check.